# Identifying and designing coils for generating parallel magnetic fields with smooth gradients

Tags: coil, magnetic-flux, optimization, field

What is this coil called (see image) (blue line is field, blue circle is clockwise oriented coil, red circle is counter-clockwise oriented coil), and are there any tools that help design it?

[image: drawing of desired field]

Basically the coils are on a flat surface, and the field is parallel to that surface at some distance. Obviously two counter-rotating loops will generate this field, but the idea would be to optimize for a smooth field while taking up the least amount of area on the surface. I tried pyCoilGen, but it wants to give me z fields with a gradient in the x direction, not a uniform field in the x direction.

Comment: Maybe try Helmholtz coils

Comment: You can't have smooth fields if you put the coils in that direction, also define smooth with a function or a line in the diagram.

Comment: using a set of coils to shape the field into as uniform of a Bx field as possible at a distance R from in between the coils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Butterfly coil.  Often used in TCMS research. This page provides a rundown on application, and includes an example plot of field intensity: 
https://www.yingchi-tms.com/butterfly-coil-a-magnetic-stimulation-coil-widely-used-in-clinical-and-scientific-research/